# Why does it take 2 button clicks to get data shown in an input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, button

I have a button 'new_tax_button_post_tag' that  when pressed adds data to "value" of post_tag.
It is a from a form that I've created with a plugin. (The values are tags in wordpress by the way)

I have created an input box named "fieldID3" that will get the data in "value" and put it in the field.

The problem is that when I press the 'new_tax_button_post_tag' button, only the data gets sent to "value" but not to the input box. I have to press it a second time to show up in input box "fieldID3".

How do I make it so that as soon as I press the "new_tax_button_post_tag" button, the data gets passed into the input field without having to press it a second time?

For further clarification, it seems as though the "value" is in queue, even though the data is present in "value", but not on the input box.

```
 <input type="text" id="fieldID3" name="tags" value="na">
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('input[name="new_tax_button_post_tag"]').click(function() {
 var value = $(this).val();
 $("#fieldID3").val(value); 
 });
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: Where is the location of this script in your code? Right now it seems as though your Javascript isn't wrapping in a `<script>` tag. Also, Can you post the code for the other input box you are grabbing the value from and the button please.

Comment: I did not add that code as I didnt see it was part of the function.

Comment: Another thing - no quotes on the selector. `$(“input[name=new_tax_button_post_tag]”)`

Comment: I would also try putting the value in a different HTML attribute such as `data-value=“$value”` and then grab it using the `$(this).attr(‘data-value’);’